# How to take the last occurance of the "begin with" using regex?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have this regex:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {



    String str = "my name is my name is jack";


    pattern = "my.*?jack"; 

    pr = Pattern.compile(pattern);

    matcher = pr.matcher(str);
    while (matcher.find()){
        list.add(matcher.group(0));
    }

    System.out.println (list.get(0));

}
```

Which is supposed to match from "my" and to "jack". At the moment, it is matching on the whole string which is not suprising. What I want to achieve is: match on the last "my" if "jack" is not found.

Current output:
my name is my name is jack

Wanted output:
my name is jack.

I know that I can substring* so that I get the last value of "my", so that the first occurance is totally ignored - but it will only break other string I might want to use - where the all the occurances but the last is removed.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Thanks. Hopefully my question isn't too vague or unclear. Please tell me if so.

*`str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("my"))`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this negative lookahead based regex:

```
my(?:(?!\bmy\b).)*?jack
```

Here `(?:(?!\bmy\b).)*` matches any character if next position doesn't have `my`, thus making sure that there is no instance of `my` between `my` and `jack`

`\b` is for word boundary.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yU9kW3/1)

Comment: Or get rid of the lazy quantifier at all with `my(?:(?!\b(?:my|jack)\b).)*jack`.

Answer (score 0):

if i understood your question correctly :p try following

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
        final String str = "my name is my name is jack";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*(my.*?jack)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.err.println(matcher.group(1));
        }

    }
}
```